# AWS s3 Provide access via CORS or access points? 403 forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, amazon-s3-access-points

I'm uploading videos to an AWS s3 bucket. That's working great.
I now need to render those videos via Nationbuilder templates, which will look like `<video><source src="...s3_url"></video>`

From my current testing, I'm getting a 403 forbidden error when the page tries to load the video, but when I visit the s3 link I CAN view the video.

**What I've tried:**

- I've 'unblocked' ALL public access [image]
- I tried the opening CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

- I tried opening via "Bucket policies":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I can't tell, is where/how I should be giving permission for my website "videoexample.com" to access the s3 bucket.**

The possibilities from what I've read so far seem to be:

1. CORS *(AWS > S3 > Bucket > Permissions)*
2. "access control lists" (ACLs)
3. "bucket policies"
4. "access point policies"
5. or possibly "Access Points"
6. or still possibly via IAM: `s3:PutObjectAcl`, or `s3:PutObject`.

> From AWS > S3 > Bucket > Permissions
>
> **Block public access (bucket settings)** Public access is granted to buckets and objects through access control lists (ACLs), bucket
> policies, access point policies, or all.

I'd really appreciate any pointers/suggestions/explanations.

Will continue reading in the meantime.

Best

Pete

Comment: Did you grant public read with either a bucket policy or ACL? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @jingx - just tried the bucket policy, will try the ACL now. I note the linked permission guide is for a website hosted with a bucket, rather than my use-case which is storing videos for a different website

Comment: Well if I read your post correctly, you *are* effectively hosting a static web site out of the bucket. It's just that everything on that web site is a video, linked to from another web site.

Comment: Hmm - possibly - is it different because it's being fetched (via some ajax kinda thing?) by the video component? Rather than a website which is fetched by a... ...uh... browser request?

Comment: Still a link... ajax requests are still http(s) requests...